# Introducing the new, general purpose Engineering SE site

Tags: discussion

For those of you interested in asking more engineering focused questions (e.g. mechanical, structural, computer, systems, etc...), we have just launched a new, general purpose [Engineering beta SE site](http://engineering.stackexchange.com)